# JAXB ymaps+gml не получается собрать

Tags: jaxb, gml

**ymaps.xsd -основной файл**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
xmlns:ymaps="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="gml.xsd"/>
<!--===============================================-->
<xs:element name="ymaps">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Корневой элемент для экземляра ymaps</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ymaps:_Extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="ymaps:GeoObjectCollection" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!--===============================================-->
<xs:element name="_Extension" type="ymaps:AbstractExtensionType" abstract="true"/>
<xs:complexType name="AbstractExtensionType" abstract="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Базовый тип для расширения YMapsML документа</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:complexType>

<!--===============================================-->
<xs:element name="GeoObject" type="ymaps:GeoObjectType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<xs:complexType name="GeoObjectType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Объект с которым ассоциирована геоинформация и который может быть показан на фоне карты </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="gml:_Geometry" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="ymaps:style" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="ymaps:attribution" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<xs:element name="GeoObjectCollection" type="ymaps:GeoObjectCollectionType" abstract="false" substitutionGroup="gml:_FeatureCollection"/>
<xs:complexType name="GeoObjectCollectionType" abstract="false">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureCollectionType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ymaps:style" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="ymaps:attribution" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<!--===============================================-->
<xs:element name="AnyMetaData" type="ymaps:AnyMetaDataType" substitutionGroup="gml:_MetaData">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Любые метаданные</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="AnyMetaDataType" mixed="true">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractMetaDataType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<!--===============================================-->
<xs:element name="style" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="attribution" type="xs:string"/>
```

**binding.xjb**

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='locatorAttrs']">
        <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='xlink:title']">
            <jxb:property name="title1"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='arcAttrs']">
        <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='xlink:title']">
            <jxb:property name="title2"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**Ошибка**

```
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
       line 1088 of file:/maps/geometryPrimitives.xsd 
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
       line 90 of file:/maps/geometryBasic2d.xsd
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
       line 99 of file:/maps/feature.xsd
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
       line 115 of file:/maps/feature.xsd
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
       line 298 of file:/maps/defaultStyle.xsd
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
       line 317 of file:/maps/defaultStyle.xsd
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
       line 257 of file:/maps/defaultStyle.xsd
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
       line 276 of file:/maps/defaultStyle.xsd
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
       line 206 of file:/maps/defaultStyle.xsd 
...
```

**При поиске в инете - bindingGML.xjb**
http://www.ogcnetwork.net/jaxb4ogc - отсюда

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc inheritance">

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings
        fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="false"
        typesafeEnumBase="xs:string"
        typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" 
        generateIsSetMethod="true">
        <xjc:noValidator />
        <xjc:noValidatingUnmarshaller />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/geometryBasic0d1d.xsd " 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <!--jaxb:bindings node="xs:attributeGroup[@name='SRSInformationGroup']">
            <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1.SRSInformationGroup</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:attributeGroup[@name='SRSReferenceGroup']">
            <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1.SRSReferenceGroup</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings-->
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractGeometryType']">
            <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1.SRSReferenceGroup</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='DirectPositionType']">
            <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1.SRSReferenceGroup</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='DirectPositionListType']">
            <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1.SRSReferenceGroup</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='VectorType']">
            <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1.SRSReferenceGroup</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='EnvelopeType']">
            <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.v_3_1_1.SRSReferenceGroup</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>



    <!-- ...

    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractCurveType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractCurveType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractGeometricPrimitiveType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractGeometricPrimitiveType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractGeometryType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractGeometryType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='CoordType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.CoordType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='DirectPositionListType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.DirectPositionListType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='DirectPositionType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.DirectPositionType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='GeometryArrayPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.GeometryArrayPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='GeometryPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.GeometryPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='PointArrayPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.PointArrayPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='PointPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.PointPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='PointType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.PointType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    -->
</jaxb:bindings>



<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/gmlBase.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_Object']">
        <xjc:dom/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <!-- ...
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='StringOrRefType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.StringOrRefType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MetaDataPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MetaDataPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractGMLType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractGMLType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    -->
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/basicTypes.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">

    <!-- ...
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='CoordinatesType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.CoordinatesType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='CodeType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.CodeType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    -->
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/geometryPrimitives.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">

    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_Solid']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="ASolidElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/geometryAggregates.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">

    <!-- ...
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiGeometryPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiGeometryPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiGeometryType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiGeometryType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiLineStringPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiLineStringPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiLineStringType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiLineStringType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiPointPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiPointPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiPointType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiPointType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiPolygonPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiPolygonPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MultiPolygonType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.MultiPolygonType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractGeometricAggregateType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractGeometricAggregateType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    -->
</jaxb:bindings>


<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/geometryBasic0d1d.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_Curve']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="ACurveElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <!-- ...
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='LineStringPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.LineStringPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='LineStringType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.LineStringType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    -->
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/geometryBasic2d.xsd " 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_Surface']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="ASurfaceElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_Ring']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="ARingElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <!-- ...
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='PolygonType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.PolygonType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='PolygonPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.PolygonPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='LinearRingPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.LinearRingPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='LinearRingType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.LinearRingType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractSurfaceType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractSurfaceType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractRingPropertyType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractRingPropertyType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='AbstractRingType']">
        <inheritance:implements>net.opengis.gml.AbstractRingType</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    -->
</jaxb:bindings>




<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/defaultStyle.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='graphStyle']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="GraphStylePropertyElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='topologyStyle']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="TopologyStylePropertyElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='labelStyle']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="LabelStylePropertyElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='geometryStyle']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="GeometryStylePropertyElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='featureStyle']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="FeatureStylePropertyElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_Style']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="AStyleElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>


</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/coverage.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:simpleType[@name='IncrementOrder']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="PLUS_X_PLUS_Y" value="+x+y"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="PLUS_X_MINUS_Y" value="+x-y"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="MINUS_X_PLUS_Y" value="-x+y"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="MINUS_X_MINUS_Y" value="-x-y"/>
        </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>


<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/base/feature.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='_FeatureCollection']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="AFeatureCollectionElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/smil/smil20.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.w3.smil.v_2_0"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:attributeGroup[@name='structureModuleAttrs']/xs:attribute[@name='class']">
        <jaxb:property name="ClassName"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="gml/3.1.1/smil/smil20-language.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.w3.smil.v_2_0.language"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

**Ошибка**

```
[ERROR] The prefix "jaxb" for element "jaxb:bindings" is not bound.
       line 21 of file:/maps/bindingGML.xjb
```

Я не понимаю, как все это запустить. При любых попытках- вываливается ошибка. А мне надо собрать всё это воедино.